# How can I get Average Per hour excluding 10+ Minute differences

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, average

I have a list of times. Every time an action is done it adds the time it happened to a log file. I would like to get the average for actions/hour. But I don't want to average in the times that there is a gap between actions greater then 10 minutes.

So for example:

```
   +--------------------+
    11:09 AM    |      
   +--------------------+
    11:02 AM    |      
   +--------------------+
    10:57 AM    |      
   +--------------------+
    10:50 AM    |4 actions 29 minutes - *12:04-10:50 = 1 hour 14 minutes >= 10 minutes 
   +--------------------+
    12:04 PM    |      
   +--------------------+
    12:01 PM    |      
   +--------------------+
    12:01 PM    |      
   +--------------------+
    11:56 AM    |      
   +--------------------+
    11:56 AM    |      
   +--------------------+
    11:55 AM    |      
   +--------------------+
    11:55 AM    |      
   +--------------------+
    11:55 AM    |8 actions 9 minutes *1:19-11:55 = 1 hour 24 minutes >= 10 minutes
   +--------------------+
    1:19 PM     |      
   +--------------------+
    1:18 PM     |      
   +--------------------+
    1:18 PM     |      
   +--------------------+
    1:17 PM     |      
   +--------------------+
    1:17 PM     |      
   +--------------------+
    1:16 PM     |      
   +--------------------+
    1:16 PM     |      
   +--------------------+
    1:16 PM     |8 actions 3 minutes *1:16-1:06 = 10 minutes >= 10 minutes
   +--------------------+
    1:06 PM     |      
   +--------------------+
    1:06 PM     |      
   +--------------------+
    1:06 PM     |      
   +--------------------+
    1:06 PM     |      
   +--------------------+
    1:06 PM     |      
   +--------------------+
    1:06 PM     |6 actions 1 minute *End of Data Sample
   +--------------------+
```

26 actions complete in 42 minutes (37.1 actions/hour)

***NOT***

26 actions completed in 1 hour 57 minutes (13.3 actions/hour)

I would ***prefer*** a Formula Based Answer but if not possible then VBA will be fine too.

***Edit Extra Sample***

I want an average of how many actions are recorded for any random hour length of time but I don't want to include any time spans the are between actions done more then 10 minutes apart.

So if from *1:15-5:45* we do **1125** "actions" and from *6:30-7:30* we do **300** "actions" thats **1425** "actions" done in **5.5** hours

That ends up being about **260** "actions/hour" (1125+300 = 1425) done from (*1:15-5:45*) OR **4.5** hours plus (*6:30-7:30*) OR **1** hour for a total of **5.5** hours ***NOT*** (*1:15-7:30*) OR **6.25** hours

But if we include the time from 5:45-6:30 that nothing was done it makes the average **228** "actons/hour" much lower then the real average of used time. Hope this helps clear up any confusion

Comment: It's not clear from your sample data where the start and end points are for your "per hour" measures. For example, your last two counts seem to be in the same hour?

Comment: @TimWilliams I appologize, the question isn't how many in an hour, but how many per hour, as in consecutive actions over all or how many were done on average per any random sample of an hour, like if your a car going 65 MPH you can drive from 1-2 or 3:30-6:30 it doesn't have to be with in the same hour to get a miles per hours average. I added a different example to my question also.

Comment: @user2140261 .. you already know how to do it .. make it as codes ..

Comment: @matzone Yeah, I added an answer, I was just looking at this from the wrong point of view I think.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok, so I was CLEARLY looking at this from a completly wrong point of view, for some reason I was thinking I had to get sub averages for each time split by the 10 minute differences then get the average of averages.

Then I woke up a little and realised all I needed to to was get the amount of wasted time and just remove that from the total time of the sample!

Not sure how I over looked such a simple idea but hey whatcha going to do.

So, correct me if im wrong i haven't fully worked out this idea as I didn't have the time, nor do I have the time at the moment.

But here is a Very Rough example of what I think I need to do to get my answer, please tell me if im missing something, or feel free to clean this up and combine this stuff to simpler forms before I get to it in your own answer, the only prerequisite to this is to make sure that all times are sorted newest to oldest to newest, Witch my data is automatically set up as seeing as it is a log that is unmodified and time comes from times entered.

[image]

Comment: Did you sort your Times in your answer or are you leaving them as is, like in your question?

Comment: @Jerry Last line of the answer, the times are sorted.

Comment: The logic is different then? I mean, in the first question, you start with AM, go through PM, back to AM and back to PM. Now what if you start with 11:01 AM, get 12:12 PM, get 11:09 AM, 11:18 AM then 12:14 PM. In your initial worksheet, this would yield 5 actions in 1+1+9+1= 12 mins, whilst after sorting, this yields 5 actions, in 17+2 = 19 mins (from 11:01 AM to 11:18 AM and two 1 minute actions).

Comment: @Jerry Not at all, the requirement wasn't actions that were in order, but actions within 10 minutes of each other so no matter how you look at the data 11:01 regardless of what is in between the data, is still within 10 minute time span from 11:09, thus should still be counted together. If that data wasn't sorted the formula would still need to count if the range above/below the active range is within 10 minutes of it not.

Comment: But you bring up a good point of what a single action with no time after it would not be considered, defiantly not an entire minute. I'll probably add some conditions to ignore any single actions that are >= 10 minutes after and before the actions surrounding it.

Comment: Ah, because I actually had something which works (at least, it seems to work for me) with your original (unsorted) data. I guess that if sorting is allowed, then you can go by your solution which would be less convoluted xD

Comment: @Jerry Please, feel free to share what you had, if it works on unsorted data it may be useful to a future reader. Again, it should probably take into consideration that data that should be grouped together might not be in order.